# problems in deleting columns in csv file and storing data?

Tags: r, csv

I have a csv file that has the following format:

```
                          1           3           1          4
1415670_at  1   8.512147859 8.196725061 8.174426394 8.62388149
1415671_at  2   9.119200527 9.190318548 9.149239039 9.211401637
1415672_at  3   10.03383593 9.575728316 10.06998673 9.735217522
1415673_at  4   5.925999419 5.692092375 5.689299161 7.807354922
```

I had made some manipulation of this data by deleting columns that are not 1 or 2:

```
m<-read.csv("table.csv")
smallerdat <- m[ c(1,2, grep("^X1$|^X2$|X1\\.|X2\\." , names(m) ) ) ]
```

Now I want to save this results again to a csv file, so I do this:

```
write.csv(smallerdat,"tablemodified.csv",ncolumns=length(smallerdat),sep=",")
```

but I got an error that says:

```
Error in cat(list(...), file, sep, fill, labels, append) : 
  argument 1 (type 'list') cannot be handled by 'cat'
```

The question that I have is how I can store into a csv file the modified table. 
Any help?

Comment: it looks like there's an error in your `grep`. I think that you need a comma before the first parentheses, to ensure that R just selects those columns.

Comment: @richiemorrisroe: Please review the "[" function. Your suggestion will return the same value as the original code. You do not need toi comma if you are selecting columns.

Comment: @Manolo, what is the `ncolumns = length(smallerdat)` supposed to achieve and where do you see such an argument in the documentation for `write.table` or `write.csv`?

Comment: @DWin wow, i did not know that. Saves me a comma in the future I guess. Thank you, and apologies for the noise.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<strike>The `write.csv` function  needs to have the file-name given as a named argument (as do all of the `write.*` cousins).</strike>   Try this instead (edited):

```
write.csv(smallerdat, file="tablemodified.csv" )
```

And my original guess applies to the save() function rather than the write.table variants.

Comment: Then drop the ncolumns argument.

Comment: is that true that the file name has to be a named argument? I've successfully used `write.csv` several times in the past without specifying `file = "somefilename"`.

Comment: No it's not true. I was conflating save and write functions

Comment: @DWin thanks for the edit, other issue is why it does not keep the original headers in the saved file (1,1,...), but it stores X, X1.1 and so on

Comment: @Manolo, I think this is addressed in [your other question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14072256/issue-with-reading-and-writing-a-csv-file-in-r-language)

Comment: excuse me @DWin, maybe it is not the procedure, but could you be so kind to give it a look to my new question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14072256/issue-with-reading-and-writing-a-csv-file-in-r-language, it has do to with this problem. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I was about to tell you to read `?read.csv` and note the "See Also" section that pointed to `write.csv`... but it doesn't.

So, use `write.csv`. :)

Comment: I have tried and nothing, there is now another error about the sep. I have taken it out and still the same problem

Comment: @Manolo: `write.csv` does not have the same arguments as `write`.  You will need to read `?write.csv` to adapt your code to your specific situation.